# I want to create a query so each project number, name, number of assigned employees, and total assigned hours are diplayed

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this code so far, but can't seem to the number of employees on eac porject.

```
SELECT  p.projno, p.pname, COUNT(e.ename) as "NUM_ASSGD_EMPS", SUM(a.num_hours) as "num_hours"
FROM    emp e, assignment a, proj p
WHERE e.empno = a.empno AND p.projno = a.projno
GROUP BY e.ename, p.Projno, p.pname;
```

Comment: Can you add the table definition and sample data to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Your group by doesn't match the aggregates.  The group by should contain the fields that don't have aggregates like sum/count.  This is just projno and pname in your case.  ename shouldn't be in the group by/  After all, if you group by that, you always get a count of 1!

So try

```
SELECT  p.projno, p.pname, COUNT(e.ename) as "NUM_ASSGD_EMPS", SUM(a.num_hours) as "num_hours"
FROM    emp e, assignment a, proj p
WHERE e.empno = a.empno AND p.projno = a.projno
GROUP p.Projno, p.pname;
```